# How can I mutably borrow a vector while iterating over it?

Tags: rust

I have a vector of `Obj`s, and I need the `do_something` method to be able to mutate that vector.

```
fn main() {
    let mut vect: Vec<Box<dyn Obj>> = vec![];
    vect.push(Box::new(ExampleObject { my_value: 1 }));
    for e in &mut vect {
        e.do_something(&mut vect);
    }
}
struct ExampleObject {
    pub my_value: i32,
}
impl Obj for ExampleObject {
    fn do_something(&mut self, state: &mut Vec<Box<dyn Obj>>) {
        state.push(Box::new(ExampleObject { my_value: 1 }));
    }
}
trait Obj {
    fn do_something(&mut self, state: &mut Vec<Box<dyn Obj>>);
}
```

Doing this gives me this error:

```
error[E0499]: cannot borrow `vect` as mutable more than once at a time
  --> core/src/lib.rs:91:24
   |
90 |     for e in &mut vect {
   |              ---------
   |              |
   |              first mutable borrow occurs here
   |              first borrow later used here
91 |         e.do_something(&mut vect);
   |                        ^^^^^^^^^ second mutable borrow occurs here
```

I understand why this invalidates the borrow checker, but I've yet to come up with a workaround that satisfies my requirements of having the implemented trait function be able to mutate the vector.

I would prefer not to have anything be cloned, but it is possible.

I know this causes an infinite loop, its just a simplified example of the structure I want to implement.

Comment: This is not just "not satisifies the borrow checker", this is a very bad idea and one of the places where a borrow checker is a good idea even in other languages. If Rust would allow you to do that, you'd have an infinite loop.

Comment: ...in case that would haven't been UB.

Comment: Could you give a less simplified example? It's hard to tell you how to fix it when we don't know what you're really trying to do.

Comment: An obvious workaround would be to store `Rc<dyn Obj>` in the `Vec` instead of boxes, and then iterate using indices. Then you can cheaply clone the `Rc` before calling the function, unborrowing the `Vec`. You still need to take into account that the length of the `Vec` may vary between iterations, but that you already know.

Answer (score 4):

You don't.  This is fundamentally unsound.

The language can't guarantee that `e.do_something()` won't somehow invalidate the `e` reference -- and, indeed, pushing onto the vector can cause a reallocation of the vector, which would invalidate `e`, and possibly also invalidate the iterator, causing future iterations of the loop to produce garbage references.

This operation would be undefined behavior in C++, but the code would compile.  Rust at least caught the problem for you.

It's not clear exactly what your code is supposed to do, so it's difficult to suggest an alternative.  It looks like a learning exercise, so I guess the exercise was successful -- you learned how Rust protects you from doing things that aren't memory-safe!

Answer (score -1):

In Rust you can't borrow more than once at a time, only one pointer borrows a mutable variable. But you can clone or copy vec to a new vec and use the new one in your function. It's not a good way to do that because it allocates more memory but it's a solution.